# Как запустить код js при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: javascript

Есть код, который запускается при обновлении страницы, а нужно, чтобы это происходило после нажатии кнопки

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const menuBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.header-for-992px__nav__ul__li_span');
    const drops = document.querySelectorAll('.header-for-992px__nav__ul-menu');

    menuBtns.forEach(el => {
        el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            let currentBtn = e.currentTarget;
            let drop = currentBtn.closest('.header-for-992px__nav__ul__li').querySelector('.header-for-992px__nav__ul-menu');


            menuBtns.forEach(el => {
                if(el !== currentBtn){
                    el.classList.remove('activee');
                }
            });

            drops.forEach(el => {
                if(el !== drop){
                    el.classList.remove('grid-header')
                }
            })

            drop.classList.toggle('grid-header')
            currentBtn.classList.toggle('activee');
        })
    })

    document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        if(!e.target.closest('.header-for-992px__nav')){
            menuBtns.forEach(el => {
                el.classList.remove('activee');
                
            });
            drops.forEach(el => {
                el.classList.remove('grid-header')
            })
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Ты добавил событие addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{}), которое срабатывает когда браузер полностью загрузил HTML и построил DOM-дерево. Если хочешь чтобы этот код срабатывал при клике на страницу, замени событие DOMContentLoaded на click: `document.addEventListener('click', () => { /* твой код */ })`

Comment: Так у вас код ничего не делает толком, только создает слушатели нажатия кнопок. Вы хотите сделать так, что бы слушатели создавались по нажатию кнопки?

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понимаю и задача стоит навесить слушателей при нажатии на кнопку, делаем что-то такое (при условии, что тег `<script>` расположен в конце body):

```js
// вместо
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
// ...
})

// пишем
const button = document.querySelector('.some-button');
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
// ...
})
```

Если `<script>` расположен где-то вначале и событие `DOMContentLoaded` все еще нужно - выносим содержимое в функцию, и ее уже вешаем на кнопку:

```js
const init = () => {
// вся логика из DOMContentLoaded
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const button = document.querySelector('.some-button');
  button.addEventListener('click', init);
});
```